# Onclick function to show specific element from menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

When i click on a element(MMA)in my left navigation bar i want it show up on the page and when i click on a other element(boxing) in my navigation i want that to be shown instead, like tabs.

I have tried but cannot get it to work, heres my code:

HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Startsida</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

                    <!-- header -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Top five facts about different martial arts</h1>
    </div>

                  <!-- Top navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li ><a href="#">Start</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Martial arts</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

                    <!-- side navigation -->
    <div class="row" id="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3" "col-lg-2" id="menu" >
        <div class="sidebar-nav" "list-group">
          <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <h1 class="head">Martial arts:</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
            <h3 class="side">Martial arts:</h3>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="ul">

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item  text-center">MMA</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item active text-center">Boxing</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Muay thai</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Kickboxing</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Takwando</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Karate</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Braziliansk jijutsu</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Wrestling</a>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

                    <!-- Main content -->

           <div class=" col-sm-9  menu-tab">

              <div class="menu-tab-content ">
                <h1>Top 5 fact about MMA</h1>
              </div>

              <div class="menu-tab-content active">
                <h1>Top 5 fact about Boxing</h1>
              </div>

          </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("div#menu>div.sidebar-nav>a").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).siblings('a.active').removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          var index = $(this).index();
          $("div.menu-tab>div.menu-tab-content").removeClass("active");
          $("div.menu-tab>div.menu-tab-content").eq(index).addClass("active");
      });
  });
```

Comment: need to see your css as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. `div#menu>div.sidebar-nav>a` looks for an `a` that's an immediate child of `div.sidebar-nav`. But in your HTML, the `a` is nested several levels below that, so it should be `div#menu>div.sidebar-nav a`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#menu>div.sidebar-nav a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('a.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var index = $(this).index();
    $("div.menu-tab>div.menu-tab-content").removeClass("active");
    $("div.menu-tab>div.menu-tab-content").eq(index).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
v
<!-- header -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Top five facts about different martial arts</h1>
</div>

<!-- Top navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Martial arts</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- side navigation -->
<div class="row" id="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3" "col-lg-2" id="menu">
    <div class="sidebar-nav" "list-group">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <h1 class="head">Martial arts:</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
          <h3 class="side">Martial arts:</h3>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="ul">

            <a href="#" class="list-group-item  text-center">MMA</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item active text-center">Boxing</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Muay thai</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Kickboxing</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Takwando</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Karate</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Braziliansk jijutsu</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center">Wrestling</a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Main content -->

  <div class=" col-sm-9  menu-tab">

    <div class="menu-tab-content ">
      <h1>Top 5 fact about MMA</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-tab-content active">
      <h1>Top 5 fact about Boxing</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
```